# What directories consume space in a given file system?

Tags: linux, filesystems

It' easy to find out in which file system a given directory is:

```
$ cd /boot
$ df -h
File System                     Size    Used  Avail      Mountpoint
/dev/sda1                        28G     14G   13G   52% /
```

Oops, `/` is fuller than expected.

But the usual suspect is relatively tame today:

```
$ du -sh /boot
124M    /boot
```

So what else is consuming 14G?

**Is there a simple way to find out what other directories consume space in that filesystem?**

---

Regarding the "possible duplicate": The typical application of the disk space analyzer type most other questions are after will exacly **not** answer my question, because it will just recurse thru all the subfolders of `/` in my case and exactly leave out the information I look for.

Comment: No. I am not searching for disk consumptions of files and folders but for folders in a certain mountpoint.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Please make your pointer to `ncdu` an answer and explain the `-x` so I can accept it.

Comment: `du  'whatever options} | sort -n` gives the answer. On Linux, "filelight" si a great utility of this (like ncdu, but prettier, and will also work on remote FS thru SSH).

Comment: @xenoid Not really, but try `du -h -d 1 | sort -h`. Little stroke for a character, but huge step for sorting.

Comment: Still stand with my options: 1) I just want to see the biggest ones anyway, I don't care if the answer is GB or bytes and 2)  -d 1 remains on the surface of things, if your culprit is just a big log file 3 levels down, you'll have to repeat your command at each level to locate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
du -x mountpoint
```

or

```
ncdu -x mountpoint
```

The `-x` option tells both tools not to cross filesystem boundaries. In most cases you will need `sudo`. The latter command offers you a quite convenient interactive interface; but the former should be available out of the box on many systems.

Comment: thanks :) This solves my current issue. But what to do when I cannot install additional software?

Comment: `sudo du -xh -d 1 /` works great for the original question!